# How can I access the results of IHealthChecks from my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, health-monitoring, health-check

I have implemented a HealthCheck similar to this (example taken from: [HERE](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/samples/HealthChecks.Sample/Startup.cs))

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<RandomHealthCheck>("random"); // <--- the important line
                
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app
                .UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true
                })
                .UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
        }

        public class RandomHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
        {
            public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow.Minute % 2 == 0)
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy());
                }

                return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy(description: "failed",exception:new InvalidCastException("Invalid cast ")));
            }

        }
    }
```

They are working successfully. I have a reachable API over http with status'es and also a HealthCheck UI displaying Status, Description & Duration. But I can't figure out how to do one thing:

How can I access the result of the health check programatically? Like it's status or time taken. I would like my controller to check the last run's (or current status) of a given check before performing an action. Is my only way to call my own health check api provided via middleware?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. A bit surprising. I thought maybe IHealthCheckPublisher might be of help here.

Comment: I simply made a public static class with my typeOf(int) counter, write back to it as soon as the HealthCheck runs and read it when I need its status.